# How Can I Set a Field as Required Dynamically Using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have several fields that only need to be displayed depending on selections in other fields. When these fields are displayed, they are also required. First, I tried to just hide the field in the view. But, the field is set to be required in the view model, so the ModelState comes back as invalid since the field is required. For now, I am creating several different view models to handle all the different possibilities, but this is getting cumbersome since there are dozens of variations for the form in the view. Is there some better way to get the results I need? For example, could I use just one model with all the fields there, then hide them in the view, but only make them required when they need to be displayed? Maybe I could add the data annotation in the ActionResult in the controller dynamically?

I found another post that might be the same question here: [ASP.NET MVC 3: programmatically add DataAnnotation (RequiredAttribute) to view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057199/asp-net-mvc-3-programmatically-add-dataannotation-requiredattribute-to-view-m)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement `IValidatableObject`. This way you can get conditional validation on your model properties.

```
 public class MyViewModel : IValidatableObject
    { 
        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
        { 
            if (Condition here) 
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Validation error");
            }
            if (Other Condition here) 
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Other Validation error");
            }
        }
    }
```

Another option is [MVC Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Is there a way to use this concept with the condition in the ActionResult, rather than the view model? I'm not sure how this helps. I think this is just giving me different error messages.

Comment: That Foolproof Validation seems useful. I will look into that more.